# is it possible recover all codes from so(Shared Object) file?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering

I am really curious that it is possible to recover all codes from so(Shared Object) file.

I made libxxx.so with 2 C files and 2 C header files.

And I removed original files except libxxx.so.

Can I remake those original files from this so file?

1. I want to know is it possible.
2. Then How? give me some clues.

Thanks.

Comment: If all you have is a binary file, even a single object file from a single source file, it's impossible to get back the original source used to make that binary. If it contains debug information you can get back *some* things, like variable and function names, but if it's stripped of debug information then there simply isn't any information available about the original source file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. I got it. Now I have to recoding all of my files for very little edit. Anyway, Thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get certain things back such as method names, and number of arguments from those variables, but no, you cannot decompile a binary .so file back to its original source.

Comment: Thanks. That is enough for now:D